# How can I create a custom assignment using a replacement function?

Tags: r

I have defined a function called `once` as follows:

```
once <- function(x, value) {
    xname <- deparse(substitute(x))
    if(!exists(xname)) {
        assign(xname, value, env=parent.frame())
    }
    invisible()
}
```

The idea is that `value` is time-consuming to evaluate, and I only want to assign it to `x` the first time I run a script.

```
> z
Error: object 'z' not found
> once(z, 3)
> z
[1] 3
```

I'd really like the usage to be `once(x) <- value` rather than `once(x, value)`, but if I write a function `once<-` it gets upset that the variable doesn't exist:

```
> once(z) <- 3
Error in once(z) <- 3 : object 'z' not found
```

Does anyone have a way around this?

ps: is there a name to describe functions like `once<-` or in general `f<-`?

Comment: they are called replacement functions

Comment: @Andrie: are there coding style guidelines on SO?  My personal preference is for more whitespace, but if there are coding standards here I could save editors time by following them in future.

Comment: @pete Too much white space on a web page means the question no longer fits on a single screen and becomes very hard to read.  Is that official SO guideline? Probably not.  If you don't like it, feel free to revert to your original.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per item [3.4.4](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/manual/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment) in the R Language Reference, something like a names replacement is evaluated like this:

```
 `*tmp*` <- x
 x <- "names<-"(`*tmp*`, value=c("a","b"))
 rm(`*tmp*`)
```

This is bad news for your requirement, because the assignment will fail on the first line (as x is not found), and even if it would work, your `deparse(substitute)` call will never evaluate to what you want it to.

Sorry to disappoint you

Comment: It's good to know one way or the other.  Now I can just rename my function `assign_once` and stop procrastinating.  Also, the RLR calls `f<-` a "complex assignment" which will help me if I need to search for it in future.

Comment: Well, it's my favorite part of the RLR. Any time I'm bugged, it turns out this section has something to do with it.

Answer (score 7):

If you are willing to modify your requirements slightly to use square brackets rather than parentheses then you could do this:

```
once <- structure(NA, class = "once")
"[<-.once" <- function(once, x, value) {
    xname <- deparse(substitute(x))
    pf <- parent.frame()
    if (!exists(xname, pf)) assign(xname, value, pf)
    once
}


# assigns 3 to x (assuming x does not currently exist)
once[x] <- 3
x # 3

# skips assignment (since x now exists)
once[x] <- 4
x # 3
```

Comment: Wow, that's beautiful and horrible at the same time.  Love it.

Comment: Cool!  I used this approach to create a multi-return operator, similar to python.